# qemu mips undefined instruction

Tags: assembly, mips, qemu

I am experimenting with the MIPS architecture using the qemu simulator. However, I get an undefined instruction exception (code 10 in the cause register) when I try to execute an swm instruction generated by the compiler in one of the prologues. I can't find the definition for this instruction in any of the Imagination Tech MIPS ISA documentation. What am I missing here?

Comment: According to google this is part of the micromips instruction set and the qemu TODO file says _"Unimplemented ASEs: microMIPS DSP r1 & r2 encodings"_. Maybe you can tell your compiler not to generate such instructions.

Comment: Thank you! That was pretty much it... I was numb not to check the microMIPS documentation.